# react-native issue with navigator invoked within navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native and ES6. I have all state in "Parent" Component. A user clicks a button in "Child" Component. It then grabs their GPS location (one function), post results via AJAX (another function) and finally redirect to a success page. The Child is loaded with a navigator call here:

```
<ChildComponent btnClick={this._getGps.bind(this)} />
```

Above is working as expected and the parent Component looks like:

```
_getGps() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this._postResults(position)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2500, maximumAge: 10000}
    )
}
```

The above also works as expected. It then calls _postResults which makes a .fetch request. Also works fine and returns a valid response. The problem is accessing the navigator object from within the response function. I can not find the scope (I have tried navigator.replace and this.navigator.replace:

```
_postResults(position) {
  fetch('https://my.rest/api', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(position)
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      // this works fine
      this.setState({position:position}) 
      // here is the problem
      navigator.replace({
      id: 'SomeOtherComponent'
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error) )
}
```

navigator is always undefined. All of these functions (besides the initial button click event) are the Parent Component.

Comment: I made a quick research. It seems navigator is a global definition defined by react-native. These globals are used to make common functions reachable without importing. For example you can use fetch() directly without importing it because it is already binded. check the document below https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/4252ac75eaf04aa9d57027e91bf7665717ed4eab/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js it explains a lot.

Comment: @BurakKarasoy Yes for sure I understand. The first function call works as expected. But the global scope is not available after the second function call. It is as if the environment is isolated. Not sure where or how. I do not mind passing in a reference to navigator, however, all attempts have failed.  Looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this. Looks like the global constants are not available when a function is passed as a reference even if that function originated in the same file the constants where declared. 'this' refers to the Component object. From the parent, when I include the ChildComponent, I pass the navigator object via bind:

```
<ChildComponent btnClick={this._getGps.bind(this, navigator)}
  navigator={navigator} />
```

When I call the parent _getGps function from ChildComponent the navigator is passed in automatically via the n variable (which is then passed to _postResults:

```
_getGps(n) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this._postResults(n,position)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2500, maximumAge: 10000}
    )
}
```

Finally here is a snippet from _postResults:

```
_postResults(n, position) {
...
```

n (navigator) is now available within _postResults and works as expected.